# Why does this PMOS LDO require no compensation to be stable?

Tags: operational-amplifier, ltspice, simulation, ldo, stability

LDOs with PMOS pass transistors are prone to oscillation due to positive feedback problems as discussed e.g. [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/69798/designing-stable-pmos-voltage-regulator?rq=1).

Now the below simple circuit is basically a PMOS LDO, but seems stable in both time and frequency analysis, both in LTspice and CircuitLab. It does not require output capacitors, but they can be added to improve supply impedance at moderate and high frequency. It has comparable behavior to usual LDOs.

I am not very familiar with "classical circuits" and the inner workings of operational amplifiers and I wonder:

**What makes this circuit different from an opamp-PMOS-LDO? Is it perhaps well-known to *not* work in practise (i.e. bad simulation)?**

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fx7glr.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Another version with a NPN pair is better matched (lower offset) and even cheaper. It also seems to have slightly better bandwidth. The downside is that the minimum dropout is VGS(PMOS) - VBE(NPN). To achieve true LDO behavior, a sub-volt VGS PMOS is needed, or a diode in series with both NPN bases.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fen2K9.png)</sup>

Comment: Which PMOS LDO is that? do you have a datasheet?

Comment: What if your load isn't just a resistor?

Comment: @DKNguyen Its just a placeholder. I tested with many different reactive loads, capacitances and load steps...

Comment: @ChristianidisVasileios it's just a Spice circuit that performs low-dropout voltage regulation.

Comment: I don't know much about this topology, but just to make sure...would the perfect matching of the NMOS's (due to it being a simulation) have any effect on stability?  To test it, you can make an extra copy/pasted `.model` statement in LTspice to slightly adjust parameters for the 2nd one.

Comment: @SteKulov I believe not. But this will affect offset from the reference.. However the offset will be anyway in the 10s of mV because of the difference in current through M1 and M2.

Comment: @SteKulov *would the perfect matching of the NMOS's (due to it being a simulation) have any effect on stability?* In my (on-chip LDO designing experience) it doesn't as the stability is mainly affected by loopgain and the frequencies of the poles. Both are not affected much by mismatch of the diffpair (M1 and M2). If you would want to lower the offset you could consider putting a resistor in series with each source but that does affect the loopgain so offset at the output due to imbalance might increase.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is likely to be one of phase margin and the number of stages. Recall that a closed loop amplifier becomes unstable when the dynamics of the circuit introduce an additional 180 degree phase shift at some frequency at which there is still gain. Further, note that each pole in the circuit will contribute such a phase shift (and a gain falloff), and each stage contributes poles.

It follows that each additional gain stage contributes both increased DC gain, and an additional 90 degree phase shift near its dominant pole frequency. Together, these are a bad sign for stability -- phase hits 180 degrees at a lower frequency, while the higher gain may now hit unity at a higher frequency.

In the linked post, an LM358 is used, which creates a structure containing a unity-gain-compensated op amp having multiple stages and internal compensation, followed by another gain stage which introduces additional DC gain and a pole. Given the following figure from the datasheet, it's reasonable to suspect that the LM358 doesn't have a lot of phase margin to offset the effects of extra stages (and in general op amps aren't usually optimized to that goal):

[image]

Your structure is a single differential pair followed by a single second stage, which trades off loop gain for stability, and is far more likely to be stable because each stage contributes a single dominant pole and 90 degrees of phase shift. They have other poles, but they're likely to be well above the unity gain frequency, and thus don't strongly affect the system's stability.

A small signal closed loop stability analysis (e.g. `stb` in Spectre/Cadence, unsure about SPICE) may yield more useful findings. This is quite a simplification as I've used few numbers, and have overlooked any zeroes in the transfer function (which are generally negligible but might not be when they're in the form of large compensation capacitors and might live in either the LHP or the RHP of the *s*-domain.

Comment: Seems to make sense, it is worse than an Opamp in some respects (lacking GBW product). So it is "luckily" to slow/weak to become unstable which is similar to what @Bimpelrekkie writes.

Answer (score 5):

> Why does this PMOS LDO require no compensation to be stable?

I guess that you're just **lucky**.

The reasons why are possibly:

1. You have a limited loopgain because R2 has a low value. Often in an on-chip LDO, R2 will be the output of a current mirror making that point high impedance (much higher than your 10 kohm).
2. You have a limited loopgain because your output is loaded by a 100 ohm resistor. Try making that a 1 Mohm resistor and see what happens.
3. The PMOS output transistor (M3) has a significant input capacitance (around 900 pF), that in combination with R2 (10 kohm) gives a (dominant) pole at around 110 kHz which is a reasonably low frequency. I expect that the other poles in the circuit are at much higher frequencies. This pole at 110 kHz in combination with the low loopgain means your circuit behaves as a **first order** feedback loop. The other poles (which can cause oscillations) are at frequencies that are much higher where the loopgain will have dropped below **1** making your loop stable.

For a proper analysis, you should do a small signal analysis on this circuit!

Comment: I first thought I was lucky and replaced the NMOS and the PMOS transistor with other parts and changed both R1 & R2 for values between 1k and 1M (leaving them the same though). The outcome was, that it always was stable. Higher RL void the output of a way to sink charge, but I had to go to unreasonable values (>1M) to observe objectionable ringing. The "lucky" parameter range appears to be rather large.

Comment: *The "lucky" parameter range appears to be rather large* I think that is also due to this LDO design being not very critical. I mean, it is a simple design which works but does not have a high performance. This LDO will be **slow** due to that 110 kHz pole. It might also not be very accurate (offset between Vref and Vout) due to the low loopgain. If you want the LDO to be stable when only 1 uA is drawn from its output, things will be different. If you would make a faster, more accurate design. Things will get "less lucky".

Comment: Yes, it doesn't have very high performance. The main use case I see for this are a mixture of: high current demand, varying input voltage (+ripple), low cost/commodity components.

Comment: I explored a little more the possible uses for this design, e.g. when an opamp satisfying a certain spec would be too expensive. Indeed when changing R2 for a current mirror, things change considerably. The whole circuit becomes more "opampy". Gain is much higher, and things can become unstable quicker. Your post and nanofarad's were very helpful. Thank you.