# Discrete opamp design - unsure about real parts vs. simulation

Tags: operational-amplifier, simulation

Inspired but the [very nice answers to this previous question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/574608/why-does-this-pmos-ldo-require-no-compensation-to-be-stable), I've explored discrete opamp design a bit more. I believe I can replace several specialty opamps from designs with this in the future - a big bonus in times of uncertain availability. Besides the extremely simple scheme in the link above, here is a slightly more complex design, based on 3 dual BJTs. I don't want to use it to replace standard commodity opamps, but for special purposes. E.g. for buffering where I need very low noise and closed loop impedance, but don't care about CMRR, offset and such.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fhBrrC.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

As it is lacking the pull output and only has a push output, it is only useful for sourcing applications and can't work without load. In SPICE, this circuit achieves \$1..2\space nV/\sqrt{Hz}\$ and about \$1\space m\Omega\$ output impedance out to about 100 kHz. In SPICE it also looks highly stable after tests with various load conditions. I am worried, that it sounds a little too good to be so easy, so I believe that the simulator doesn't capture some important shortcomings of an actual discrete design.

So the **question** is: Will this be ok as an actual discrete design (with compact layout, little larger than a SOIC-8) or are there some crucial parasitics missing? I am fairly inexperienced with discrete transistor designs so I have no gut feeling.

Comment: Unless you need to go fast the *biggest* issue you will have is mismatched BJTs. In other words, you'll get a lousy CMRR and similar asymmetries. As an educative toy it would be suitable. For high end requirements they sell matched quad arrays if you want to pay for them

Comment: Thanks @LorenzoMarcantonio well as I said, in the applications I envision I don't need good offset or CMRR. This is definitely nothing that could replace all opamps. :-)

Comment: I remember such devices as CA3086, DIP or SOIC14 pins ... 5 transistors. DC-190 MHz general purpose.

Comment: @Antonio51 it doesn't appear to be widely available (checked octopart) and probably there would be no easy replacements? The whole point of this "exercise" is to use something that does not rely on anything special or proprietary.

Comment: Ok. I understood. For such "replacement", it would be interresting to learn "pairing" of devices and mounting them by "pair" for same temperature behavior. I will try a simulation also. Good exercice. :) I forget. You can easily add a "balancing" offset (2 resistors and a pot if necessary.

Comment: MAT14 from Analog (BJTs) or  ALD1106 from ALD (MOSFETs). Just be sure to be seated before looking at the price tag

Comment: Don't forget that any model will be only as good as the models within. First and foremost test your transistors, one by one if you have to, and make sure they come "close enough" to what you have on the test bench. If you're only using `.model` definitions, chances are parasitics will not be too well defined. Otherwise, look at hypex.nl for some papers where Bruno uses discrete implementations of various things (even a DAC, IIRC).

Comment: @tobalt "The whole point of this 'exercise' is to use something that does not rely on anything special or proprietary." I used to think the same way, but had to learn that there are things you can only do on single piece of silicon (IC design) which you can't duplicate by connecting separate pieces via pins & wires (i.e. discrete design). Ex: current mirrors require precise matching; CMOS analog switches require special connection of the body/substrate. Luckily they still make matched BJT pairs. On Digi-Key it's a filter option under BJT arrays. Mouser you have to search the text "matched".

Comment: @SteKulov I agree that some things just aren't for discrete circuits. But in this case, the matching really does not matter: Even when input pair and current mirror are strongly mismatched ( factor 2 in beta and current), the only thing that will be affected strongly is offset, assymetry etc. as noted by Lorenzo and which I don't care about in this circuit as explained in the question. AC parameters, however, are virtually unaffected. I am interested if AC parameters will be affected by something beyond the scope of the sim (namely parasitics). Mismatch appears to not matter much.

Comment: @tobalt That makes sense. I mainly wanted to point out you can still buy matched pairs and they're not expensive at all. Here are some examples:  
https://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Diodes-Incorporated/BCM857BS-7-F?qs=60RJRzIpcl83Pda4UUWqGw%3D%3D  

https://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Diodes-Incorporated/DMMT3904W-7-F?qs=jL3InCUZRT6ej7BpU1jcgw%3D%3D

Answer (score 3):

I made some simulations to help.
Noise not done, measuring output impedance not done yet.

microcap12 http://www.spectrum-soft.com/download/download.shtm

DC Dynamics

[image]

TRAN

[image]

AC     See instability for Gain = 0db  --> choose capacitor C1 or higher gain.

[image]

But if you add "some" components ... it become "stable" with very little "ringing" but slew rate ... Capacitors may change a little.

[image]

Now, it is ok ?

[image]

Comment: thanks for checking with another simulator. What is your feeling about the role of parasitics ? I am most concerned that it will be very different from this in reality because of parasitics. I wouldn't use it with inverting gain though, but only as follower with shortcut between out and in-.

Comment: Ok. Will try in follower configuration. But I think that little instability will occur. I check.

Comment: In follower configuration, seems to be stable.... with big oscillation at 25 MHz !

Comment: soo. basically not stable then ?! :-) Interesting.. I didn't see any such oscillation in LTspice, but the circuit was embedded in other circuitry around it..So the oscillation might be damped by some other component. I will investigate it when I get back to it.

Comment: Yes, but look at my edit ...

Comment: Where low noise is more important than power consumption, you may want to experiment with more input stage current; up to 10mA, either reducing R1 or replacing with a current source.

Comment: @user_1818839 I noticed this, but 10k was a sufficient compromise.. Antonio: even without those additional components, when I simulate only my OP circuit in LTspice, I get only ~1 dB peaking at about 50 MHz in follower config. maybe the transistor models are different ?

Comment: Ok. Model probably different, yes, but what ? ... Last but not least : test in real components : the truth. Good luck.  :-)

Comment: I have tested with generic npn and pnp ... 0.4 db peaking ... but beta are lower (max 200) ... The other used in simulation were with beta > 500 ... Logical.

Comment: Aha! that is another important info wrt real components: Their beta might be actually scattered in a way that makes this thing unstable.. I will look into it, i.e. try different BCxxxB and BCxxxC parts in various combinations to judge the beta influence.

Comment: Or simply override the beta on one of the existing transistors.