# Adjustable MOSFET dummy load to drain PSU negative side (-12V)

Tags: power-supply, mosfet, load

I have a mission to build a dummy load to make a PSU test and found some schematics with a positive load. It worked like a charm.

[Electronic load, Problem turning MOSFET on](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/447770/electronic-load-problem-turning-mosfet-on)

But there is no information about how to drain from PSU negative side
I've searched all internet and no answers.

Please, anyone could help?

EDIT:
Hi @bobflux .
Sorry for the delay.
I´ve build this one an it worked. Thank you!
[image]

EDIT2: Hi Andrew Morton. Yes, my drawing fault :-(. There is a 100R gate resistor. Thanks!!!

Comment: Flip the schematic upside down and turn NMOS into PMOS.

Comment: The IRF9640 is missing the gate resistor that the other transistor has. Is that just a drawing error? Also, your edit should probably have been an answer: you're allowed to answer your own questions.